# Take a value from URL php get method

Tags: php

```
http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.html?id=5678
```

I have to take the value of id with php.
I tried in this way but it doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    $variabile_get = $_GET['id']; 
    echo( $variabile_get);
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't see nothing. Someone can help me????

Comment: .html != .php. your file is not interpreted.

Comment: ..you'd also notice that it's not interpreted if you looked at the source of the page (you'd find out that there's raw PHP tags in there that aren't shown because HTML thinks that it's a HTML tag).

Comment: njzK2 is correct, you're using the wrong file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print variable value in HTML you should always use escape function as for example htmlspecialchars to prevent attack on your site so the code should be:

```
   <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
        $variabile_get = $_GET['id']; 
        echo htmlspecialchars($variabile_get);  
      ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Of course if you expect that id is int you could also change lines:

```
        $variabile_get = $_GET['id']; 
        echo htmlspecialchars($variabile_get);
```

to

```
        $variabile_get = intval($_GET['id']); 
        echo $variabile_get;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

**jsonint.html** it should be .php file not like .html

```
   <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
        $variabile_get = $_GET['id']; 
        echo $variabile_get;  //your wrong code here
      ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code, **you just use the wrong file extension**, change it to `.php`.
Also, you must prevent your site from attacks like [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) by filter the data you received from the user, just use the [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) function, It works by changing the problematic character to html display character. and dont forget to check if the value of `$_GET['id']` is a number. use [intval()](https://www.php.net/intval) for that.

### Example

When the user enter in the data field the character ">", he can apply the tag `<script>` and do dangerous things. We DONT want him to do that, so we will apply [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the received data and the output will be `&lt;` , the browser will still display the ">" character.

### Bypassing

The user can bypass this function by using different multi-byte encoding, so we need to use the `ENT_QUOTES` option, like this:

```
   echo htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

change http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.html?id=5678
to
http://sath3g.altervista.org/jsonint.php?id=5678

use the following code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$variabile_get = $_GET['id']; 
echo $variabile_get;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the .html extension of the file to .php.  PHP won't process a file that's not identified as a PHP file.